# Express отдает не всю статику

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

```
// router.js
router.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../client/')));
router.get('/', (req, res)=> {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../client/index.html'));
});

// server.js
app.use('/', router);
```

Gulp собирает все файлы и отправляет в build-папку (проверял, действительно все файлы там находятся), и при всем при этом, в браузер подтягиваются не все файлы.

P.S.: На нужные мне файлы нода отдает 304 статус.

Comment: У вас в коде есть папка '/', есть папка '../client', и не понятно, при чем тут build-папка. Она вообще где?

Comment: build-папка, это та же самая папка, что и dev, только куда попадает весь минифицированный, оттранспайленный код.
В данном случае, "../client/" - то, откуда конкретный роутер будет забирать статику.

Comment: Отлично, появилась еще папка dev. Но не появилось у меня понимание того, какая связь между папками, упомянутыми в коде, и папками, упомянутыми в тексте.

Comment: не важно сколько папок, есть n-ое количество файлов, часть из которых express отдает, а часть попадает в no-domain.
Папки "/" нет, это роут.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

304 - это нормально. Просто сервер так настроен.